# Why does my LEFT JOIN work when I perform "SELECT * ", but fails when I select only the necessary columns?

Tags: postgresql

I'm new to SQL but I'm trying to join two tables. However, it's not working as I expected. This is in Postgresql.

Here are the tables I'm trying to join.

### My Tables

```
SELECT * FROM houses;

 id |      name      |   address   | picture
----+----------------+-------------+------------
  1 | House 1        | 440 S 3rd W | long-link2.jpg
  2 | House 2        | 538 S 5th E | long-link.jpg

SELECT house_id, trunc(avg(score), 1) FROM house_reviews GROUP BY house_id;

 house_id | trunc
----------+-------
        1 |   3.0
        2 |   3.0
```

### My JOIN statements

**Attempt 1 (works)**

```
SELECT * FROM houses
LEFT JOIN (SELECT house_id, trunc(avg(score), 1) FROM house_reviews GROUP BY house_id) AS r
ON houses.id = r.house_id;
```

**Attempt 2 (does not work)**

```
SELECT id, name, address FROM houses
LEFT JOIN (SELECT house_id, trunc(avg(score), 1) FROM house_reviews GROUP BY house_id) AS r
ON houses.id = r.house_id;
```

The only difference between the two is that I don't select the picture in the attempt 2. But attempt 2 doesn't seem to join at all. Instead it displays

```
 id |      name      |   address
----+----------------+-------------
  1 | Tuscany        | 440 S 2nd W
  2 | Mountain Lofts | 538 S 2nd W
```

meaning that it failed to join and is instead just displaying the houses table.

### My Question

I'm confused why the join failed in the second table because I removed only one arbitrary column (pictures).

Is there a way that I can join the two tables together but also exclude the pictures column from the "houses" table?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're only seeing data from `houses` because that's all you've selected.  Try this:

`SELECT
    h.id, h.name, h.address,
    r.avg_score
FROM houses h
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT house_id, trunc(avg(score), 1) avg_score
    FROM house_reviews 
    GROUP BY house_id
) AS r
ON houses.id = r.house_id;`

Comment: Sure enough. I think I just had a misunderstanding of how select queries work.